# Error Uploading to AWS S3 bucket - AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Tags: php, amazon-s3, file-upload

For S3 uploads I use

- @link http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class
- @version 0.4.0

This works perfectly for a US based S3 bucket. But for EU, this is failing with the following error

> The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: It would help tremendously if you posted a [mcve] of your code, showing what authorization mechanism you are using, etc.

Comment: TL;DR: That code is outdated and cannot be used with newer regions. Use the AWS SDK.

Comment: @EDCottrell I use the widely used http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class/ which seems to have a limitation; the solution of which I am looking for

Comment: @user4826347 Okay, but your question is still incomplete for  the same reasons I just explained. Where is *your* code using that class?

Comment: For those who wonder if and how I fixed the issue, I added .aws/credential to my machine with AWS Keys and used PHP SDK to create a wrapper. I cannot post the answer as it is marked as duplicate which I doubt... Thanks